# Why does it add 40 something?

Tags: java

```
public class calculator {
static char operator;
static String operatorWord;
static String nameOfFirstNumber;
static String nameOfSecondNumber;
static double firstNumber;
static double secondNumber;
static int response2;

public static void setResponse2(boolean b){
    if(b = true){
        response2 = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    }
    else if(b = false){
        response2 = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
    }
    else;
}

public static void setOperator(char c){
    operator = c;
}

public static void setOperatorWord(String s) throws NotAnOperatorException{
    operatorWord = s;
}


public static String getOperatorWord(char c, int i) throws NotAnOperatorException{
    if(c == '*'){
        return "Multiplication";
    }
    else if(c == '/'){
        return "Division";
    }
    else if(c =='+'){
        return "Addition";
    }
    else if(c == '-'){
        return "Subtraction";
    }
    else if(c == '%'){
        return "Remainder";
    }
    if(i < 2){
        throw new NotAnOperatorException();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void defineNameOfNumbers(char c){
    if(c == '*'){
        nameOfFirstNumber = "multiplicand";
        nameOfSecondNumber = "multiplier";
    }
    else if(c == '/'||c == '%'){
        nameOfFirstNumber = "dividend";
        nameOfSecondNumber = "divisor";
    }
    else if(c == '+'){
        nameOfFirstNumber = "addend";
        nameOfSecondNumber = "addend";
    }
    else if(c == '-'){
        nameOfFirstNumber = "subtrahend";
        nameOfSecondNumber = "minuend";
    }
}

public static double getRemainder(){
    if(operator == '/'||operator == '%'){
        return firstNumber%secondNumber;
    }
    else{
        return (Double) null;
    }
}

public static double getAnswer(){
    if(operator == '*'){
        return firstNumber*secondNumber;
    }
    else if(operator == '/'){
        return firstNumber/secondNumber;
    }
    else if(operator == '%'){
        return firstNumber%secondNumber;
    }
    else if(operator == '+'){
        return firstNumber+secondNumber;
    }
    else if(operator == '-'){
        return firstNumber-secondNumber;
    }
    else{
        return (Double) null;
    }
}

public static String getRemainderString(){
    //get the remainder & string...//
    if(operator == '/'){
        int answer = (int) (firstNumber/secondNumber);
        int remainder = (int) (firstNumber%secondNumber);
        return "\n"+answer+" remainder "+remainder;
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}



/**
 * @param args
 * @throws NotAnOperatorException 
 * @throws HeadlessException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, NotAnOperatorException {
    //end of catch statements//
    do{

        //get the operator etc. I know it's a bit overdone.//
        try{
            char operatorThing = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Operator:").charAt(0);
            setOperator(operatorThing);
            setOperatorWord(getOperatorWord(operator, 1));
            defineNameOfNumbers(operatorThing);
            }
        //catch a NotAnOperatorException (defined with NotAnOperatorException.class)//
            catch(NotAnOperatorException exc){
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                exc.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String excSentence = writer.toString();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong... Here's the rundown on what happened:\n"+excSentence+"\nWe've figured out what happened, though.\nThat's not an operator...\nRestart to rerun it, it will exit for safety.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        //catch a null pointer//
            catch(NullPointerException exc){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You clicked Cancel. Press OK to quit.");
                System.exit(0);
        }
        //catch an other exception//
            catch(Exception exc){
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                exc.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String excSentence = writer.toString();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Something went wrong... Here's the rundown on what happened:\n"+excSentence+"\nI have no idea what happened.\nRestart to rerun it, it will exit for safety.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        //get the response with "int response"//
        int response;
            response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to start "+getOperatorWord(operator, 2)+" Calc?");
    if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        String numberOne = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X"+operator+"Y=Z\nEnter the "+nameOfFirstNumber+" (the first number.)");
        firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(numberOne);
        String numberTwo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(firstNumber+operator+"Y=Z\nEnter the "+nameOfSecondNumber+" (the second number.)");
        secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(numberTwo);

        if(operator == '/'||operator == '%'){
            int response3 =
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+"="+getAnswer()+getRemainderString()+"\n Would you like to start "+getOperatorWord(operator, 2)+" Calc again?");
            if(response3 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                setResponse2(true);
            }
            else if(response3 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION||response3 == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                setResponse2(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            int response3 =
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, firstNumber+operator+secondNumber+"="+getAnswer()+"\n Would you like to start "+getOperatorWord(operator, 2)+" Calc again?");
            if(response3 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                setResponse2(true);
            }
            else if(response3 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION||response3 == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
                setResponse2(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }


    }
    while(response2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);


}

}
```

Okay I know that's a load of code. Sorry, but...
When the dialog shows up that says `"X"+operator+"Y=Z\nEnter the "+nameOfFirstNumber+" (the first number.)"`, if I type 1 (in the next dialog) it says `"48.0Y=Z"` (if its in division mode.) It doesn't even show the operator *and* I didn't type 48, I typed 1. In other modes it says some number from 40 to 50. What's going on here? It's very strange...

Thanks!

**[EDIT]** Okay it has something to do with ASCII. But how can I fix it?
**[EDIT]** And why does it not show the operator?

Comment: Hint: 48 to 57 are the ASCII codes for the digits `0` to `9`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your numbers using `String.valueOf()`method e.g.

```
String numberTwo = 
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(String.valueOf(firstNumber)+operator+"Y=Z\nEnter the "
                       +nameOfSecondNumber+" (the second number.)");
```

Comment: @Minecrafterguy64: Try simple thing as `char ch = 'a'; System.out.println(ch); System.out.println(ch+2);` You will see the difference. First statement will print `a`, while second will print `99` (97+2), where 97 is ASCII value of 'a'. Bottomline summary is - `char gets auto promoted to int in the required context as in second example`.

Comment: Okay thanks! Also I noticed you answered/commented on my other questions too! lol

Answer (score 3):

Quick hint: `48` is the *ASCII CODE* for the character `0`.   `49` for `1`, `50` for `2` etc.

The source of this bug are snippets like:

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog(firstNumber+operator+"Y=Z\nEnter the "....`

Whereby `firstNumber` (a double value) is "added" to a character value.
(note this pattern in found several times throughout the source file).

**To fix this you need to either**...
  -  make the operator variable a string variable
  - use String.valueOf(whatever_numeric_type_variable_at_hand)
  - **use a better idiom to to build your string** such as:
           `"%f %x Y=Z...".format(firstNumber, operator)`

The best approach is probably the latter, with `string.format()` as it offer more control over the way the string is formatted, and a clearer read of what is variable and what is fixed text.  This also introduces the ability to support different formats depending on the cultural locale.